# Duck Typing Annotations in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, duck-typing

I am trying to add a type annotation to a function input argument that is a `dataclass` with attributes that overlap with another `dataclass`, which actually gets passed in as an input argument.

Consider the following code:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TypeVar


@dataclass
class Foo:
    a: str
    zar: str

@dataclass
class Car(Foo):
    b: str


@dataclass
class CarInterface:
    a: str
    b: str


mar = TypeVar("mar", bound=CarInterface)


def blah(x: mar):
    print(x.a)

car_instance = Car(a="blah blah", zar="11", b="bb")
blah(car_instance)
```

In this example, I'm trying to create my own type annotation `mar` which is bound by `CarInterface`. I want to check that whatever class is passed into `blah()` at least has `a` and `b` attributes (don't care if the class has other attributes such as `zar`). I want to do it this way because class `Car` (which actually gets passed in) is one of many classes that will be written in the future and passed into this function.

I also want it to be very easy to define a new `Car`, so I would like to avoid abstract classes as I don't think the added complexity is worth mypy being happy.

So I'm trying to create `mar` which uses duck typing to say that `Car` satisfies the interface of `CarInterface`.

However, I get two mypy errors.

The first is on the `mar` annotation in `def blah`

```
TypeVar "mar" appears only once in generic function signaturePylancereportInvalidTypeVarUse
```

And the other is where I pass `car_instance` into `blah()`

```
Argument of type "Car" cannot be assigned to parameter "x" of type "bar@blah" in function "blah"
  Type "Car" cannot be assigned to type "CarInterface"
    "Car" is incompatible with "CarInterface"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

Comment: This is what [protocols](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) are for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Protocol` to define `CarInterface` rather than a `dataclass`:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Protocol

@dataclass
class Foo:
    a: str
    zar: str

@dataclass
class Car(Foo):
    b: str

class CarInterface(Protocol):
    a: str
    b: str

def blah(x: CarInterface):
    print(x.a)

car_instance = Car(a="blah blah", zar="11", b="bb")
blah(car_instance)
```

The above code will typecheck fine, but if you try to pass `blah` a `Foo` instead of a `Car` you'll get a mypy error like this:

```
test.py:22: error: Argument 1 to "blah" has incompatible type "Foo"; expected "CarInterface"
test.py:22: note: "Foo" is missing following "CarInterface" protocol member:
test.py:22: note:     b
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

A `Protocol` can be used as the bound for a `TypeVar`, but it's only necessary to use a `TypeVar` if you want to indicate that two variables not only implement the protocol but are also the same specific type (e.g. to indicate that a function takes any object implementing `CarInterface` and returns the same exact type of object rather than some other arbitrary `CarInterface` implementation).